Windows machine documentation tool (Installed application, Group Policies, Services, etc)
I am looking for a good tool to document current state of the windows machine.
I would like to get some recommendation for a tool that can generate a human readable report for a windows machines with information such as Installed applications, Group Polices, Services, Local Users, Hardware Information, OS information, etc.
I have searched online but could not find a comprehensive tool, most of the tools I found are either for one or two of above mentioned pieces of information or are network based.
What I need is a software I can run individually on each machine as the machines are not on a network or domain.
